# How to add aria-labelledby="*" attributes to common components that will be repeated multiple times in a page?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a common dropdown component that will be used multiple times in a given page:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="I cannot add a static ID here since this will be repeated multiple times in a page" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="How to reference the above button here?">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I do not want to add an ID for my button since it is going to be repeated multiple times in a page.
Is there any other way to add `aria-labelledby` attributes here without dynamically generating an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aria-labelledby`, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute):

> contains the element IDs of labels in objects such as input elements, widgets, and groups

If you want to use `labelledby` you would need to have IDs. However, you can use *different* IDs for different buttons and have the items use the relevant ID as part of their `labelledby` attribute.

If you're using a content management system you should be able to write a loop that will generate an ID with a number to have each button associated with a different ID, and re-use that ID as part of the `labelledby`.

The value of `labelledby` doesn't need to make sense; it's a hook that tells assistive technology "Thing A is labelled by the thing with this ID".